# React native app doesn`t fill the whole screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I can't get my app to fill the whole screen. Whatever i do, there is always a white bar on the bottom of the page. It's so strange because it works on some devices but not others. i'm going crazy over this!

I`ve tried const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window'); and setting the app height with that, and it actually worked once, but now i can't get it to work again. i`ve tried rewrapping everything in different ways, with different views and scrollviews.

ps.: i removed all functions and useless code so it's not too much code, but
here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Switch,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground,
  Image,
  Linking,
  StatusBar,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import { ScaledSheet } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
          style={styles.teste}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>

          <StatusBar backgroundColor="#50a9f3" />

          <ImageBackground source={require('./background.png')} style={styles.imagemBackground}>


              <View style={styles.campos}>
                <Image
                  style={{ width: 110, height: 110, alignSelf: 'center' }}
                  source={require('./logo.png')}
                />
                <View style={styles.item}>
                  <Text style={styles.texto}>M²s do ambiente</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputText}
                    keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                    onChangeText={mQuadrado => this.setState({ mQuadrado })}
                  />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.item}>
                  <Text style={styles.texto}>Nº de pessoas</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputText}
                    keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                    onChangeText={pessoas => this.setState({ pessoas })}
                  />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.item}>
                  <Text style={styles.texto}>Nº de eletrodomésticos</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputText}
                    keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                    onChangeText={eqps => this.setState({ eqps })}
                  />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.item}>
                  <Text style={styles.texto}>Nº de janelas </Text>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputText}
                    keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
                    onChangeText={jnls => this.setState({ jnls })}
                  />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.switch}>
                  <Text style={styles.texto}>Recebe luz solar </Text>
                  <Switch
                    style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: 0.9 }, { scaleY: 0.9 }] }}
                    thumbColor="#ffffff"
                    trackColor={{ true: '#c0c0c0' }}
                    value={this.state.switch}
                    onValueChange={value => this.setState({ switch: value })}
                  />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.input}>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.opacity} onPress={this.calcular}>
                    <Text style={styles.textoCalcular}>CALCULAR</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.resultadoBox}>
                  <Text style={styles.textoResultado}>Você precisará de</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.resultado}>{btu == '0' ? null : btu + '.000 BTUS'}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.banner}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.bannerContainer}
                  onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://matum.com.br/produtos-sisum/')}>
                  <Text style={styles.bannerTexto}>Gerencie suas manutenções preventivas e corretivas</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.bannerTexto}>Relatório PMOC simples</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.bannerTextoX}>Saiba mais</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>

          </ImageBackground>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const heightCerto = height - StatusBar.currentHeight;
const styles = ScaledSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  teste: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  imagemBackground: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  campos: {
    flex: 95,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    padding: '20@s',
    paddingTop: '12@s',
  },
  item: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  switch: {
    paddingTop: '15@s',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flex: 1,
  },
  textoCalcular: {
    fontSize: '15@s',
    color: '#ffffff',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowRadius: 2,
  },
  input: {
    padding: '20@s',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  opacity: {
    backgroundColor: '#50a9f3',
    borderWidth: '1.5@s',
    borderRadius: '10@s',
    borderColor: '#000000',
    width: '190@s',
    height: '39@s',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  resultadoBox: {
    flex: 2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,100,100,0.5)',
    margin: 0,
    borderColor: 'rgba(100,100,100,0.5)',
    borderRadius: '10@s',
  },
  resultado: {
    fontSize: '28@s',
    color: 'white',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowRadius: 5,
  },
  banner: {
    flex: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(140,140,140,0.5)',
    margin: 0,
    borderColor: '#50a9f3',
    borderWidth: '1.5@s',
    borderRadius: '10@s',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  bannerContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  bannerTexto: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: '12@s',
  },
  bannerTextoX: {
    color: '#50a9f3',
    fontSize: '10@s',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowRadius: 4,
  },
  inputText: {
    fontSize: '12@s',
    color: 'white',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowRadius: 5,
    height: '38@s',
  },
  texto: {
    fontSize: '13@s',
    color: '#ffffff',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowRadius: 5,
  },
  textoResultado: {
    fontSize: '16@s',
    color: 'white',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowRadius: 5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about the image background but not totally sure. I was able to get it to stretch to the full height by adding the following height declaration:

```
imagemBackground: {
  flex: 1,
  height: height,
},
```

link to example: https://snack.expo.io/r1Y-zpwMH

Answer (score 2):

You are using flex:1 many times in style that is the problem.
please give flex:1 in container style and remove all flex:1 in other styles instead of flex:1 you can use width and height in percentage.
like style={{width:'100%',height:'40%'}}.
Thank you!